# Get cone from occupancy grid

Tags: ros, python, octomap, nav-msgs, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Is there any built in method to get the range data in a cone-format from a `nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid` message?

I am using the Octomap package with the octomap_server on Groovy, with Python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73723/get-cone-from-occupancy-grid/) by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not think that this exists. And with no response it likely isn't available as you describe.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0